# Does corba allow a client to include it's own server stub

Tags: networking, client-server, rpc, distributed, corba

I am working on an application in which the clients send RPCs to server and also the server will be requesting services from the clients. My question is can the server have multiple client stubs and one server stub(act as client and server)? And for the clients, can they have a server stub to accept RPCs from the server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes to all those questions. You can handle the 'multiple client stubs' via a suitable data structure in the server.